# Shortcut/app to capture only the content of a window in a screenshot?

Tags: keyboard, screen-capture

```
System Software Overview:

  System Version:   macOS 10.13.6 (17G3025)
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 17.7.0
```

I would like to capture only the content of a window, without the menu. In other words, I would like to capture this:

[image]

instead than this:

[image]

I can use `Cmd`+`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`4` and then resize the capture area to just the contents of the window, but that's not very convenient...isn't there a shortcut which doesn't involve selecting areas with the mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how convenient this would be for your workflow...

- Switch to fullscreen.
- From the View menu, uncheck "Always show toolbar in full screen"
- Use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>4</kbd>  then tap the spacebar & click in the window
  This will [as always] take a snap of the entire window - but in this case it will leave out the toolbar entirely.
  Scrollbars will hide or show depending on your setting in System Prefs > General

[image]

Comment: hmmm...good idea, forcing the window to be fullscreen sometimes makes the resulting image too small to be readable. Let's see if someone else has an alternative idea.

Comment: How does it make it too small?... it's the size of your screen. Any bigger & it wouldn't fit.. the image I posted, btw, was resized before upload; the original is 2560x1440

Comment: There's a misunderstanding here: I mean that, if I have to enlarge the window to fullscreen before capturing the screen, then the result image is very large with respect to the characters (but still readable, because I have a high resolution monitor). **However**, I then have to resize the image to a smaller size if I want to put it in a document or an email, and at this point, the characters become quite small. Anyway, even if it's not ideal, this procedure answers my question, thus I'm accepting it.